# What determines whether a gym shows its banner?

Tags: pokemon-go

In my area, there are currently three Mystic gyms, and two have their banners shown while the other does not:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What determines whether a gym shows the banner of the team that controls it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on the evidence being gathered in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6iwcwa/gyms_withwithout_team_banners/?ref=search_posts), it looks like a gym will display banners if the **total CP of the Pokémon in the gym surpasses 8000.**

> Just in scanning over the active gyms in the area, it looks like Banner Flags show up when the total CP of the defending Pokémon passes a certain number. There're two that I can see from here with only 3 Pokémon on them – one with flags and one without.
>
> Has banner flags
>
> - 2985+2682+2882=8549 CP
> - Dragonite, Gyarados, Snorlax
>
> Doesn't have banner flags
>
> - 2992+2362+1686=7040 CP
> - Tyranitar, Rhydon, Gyarados

---

> Gym I could see from here had no banners when there were 3 pokemon in it: Rhydon 2744, Snorlax 1884, Gyarados 2098 = 6726.
>
> A 4th was added, Vaporeon 2079 to bring the total to 8805 which raised it and banners are flying.

---

> The two gyms near me are both bannerless with totals of 5286 (2 players) and 7551 (3 players)

---

> I've got a Gym that was at 8100 & 4 Pokémon and had banners, and is now at 7800 with the same 4 Pokémon on there, but all the banners have gone.