# New Pokémon Go gyms - no "add pokemon" button

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to add my Pokémon to a friendly gym
But there is no button.  How do I get to add my Pokémon?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The gym you are looking at is currently full. The maximum Pokémon that can be in a gym is now **6**, down from the original 10.

Contrary to the old system, you do not need to train a gym to level it up in order to make room. Once a gym is claimed by a team, 5 other players can add a unique Pokémon to the gym.

The only way to get into a friendly gym that is currently full is to wait for one of the Pokémon to be removed and put yours in its place. However, due to the gym rework, it is highly likely that when one is removed, they will all be removed (at least from personal experience).

Your best bet would be to look for a gym that is not full -- try looking for gyms [without banners](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311909/162442), as they are likely not full. Alternatively, you could go attack other gyms to take them down and claim them for your team. This is much easier now, again thanks to the gym rework.